# How to pass in values from a XMLHttprequest with .open() into a python script

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

I want to do this:

Run a python scipt with out of javascipt:

```
    function getDescription() {
        <!-- var snd_name = document.getElementById("name").value;  -->
        var url = '/cgi-bin/events.py?name=1';

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        printEvent('Client','Sent request ...');
        req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
```

The finction getDesciption is called somewhere else.

Now I pass with req.open the URL including parameters to the python script.

In the python script I like to so some thing like this:

```
import time
import cgi
import sys
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import urlparse
import urllib

result = READ_THE_PARAMETERS... I have no clue what to do here...

a = result[name]

print[a]
```

And in a I should the "1".

It is probably pretty easy, but not today for me. 
Please help.

Thank you Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parameters = cgi.FieldStorage()
a = parameters[name]
print a
```